# Doctrine2 Custom Type Not Returning Data

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, custom-type

iam regreting for last two days since came to my mind that i could create encrypted custom type, so that encryption and decryption of data would be done in that type so that i dont need to call those functions evrytime, generally to make my life easier but it turn it into living hell :/

My custom type is inserting encrypted data in the database as i intended but problem is when i need to retrive data, here is print of object that holds retrived data from database

```
    Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request Object
(
    [id:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => 2
    [clientIPAdress:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => 
    [clientHost:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => 
    [clientISP:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => 
    [clientOS:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => 
    [clientOSVersion:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => 
    [clientBrowser:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => 
    [clientBrowserVersion:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => 
    [clientLanguage:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => 
    [clientCountry:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => 
    [clientCity:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => 
    [possibleProxy:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => 
    [proxyIPAdress:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => 
    [torExitNode:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => 
    [maliciousInput:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => 
    [maliciousInputLog:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => 
    [serverIPAdress:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => 
    [serverPort:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => 
    [requestMethod:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => 
    [requestTimeFloat:Uapi\CoreBundle\Entity\Request:private] => P�a�;
)
```

Here is my Encrypted type class definition

```
    use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Uapi\CoreBundle\Provider\EncryptionProvider;

class EncryptedType extends Type {

    const ENCRYPTED = 'encrypted';

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::ENCRYPTED;
    }

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        return $platform->getVarcharTypeDeclarationSQL($fieldDeclaration);
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        return ($value === null)? null : base64_encode(EncryptionProvider::getCrypter()->encrypt($value));
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        return ($value === null)? null : base64_decode(EncryptionProvider::getCrypter()->decrypt($value));
    }
}
```

And i did register it within boot function in core bundle class

```
 $connection = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getConnection();
        if(!Type::hasType('encrypted'))
        {
            Type::addType('encrypted', 'Uapi\CoreBundle\System\DBALType\EncryptedType');
            $connection->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('encrypted', 'encrypted');
        }
```

Comment: What's the question here? What is not working? Any exceptions? What did you try already?

Comment: Just read question man, iam on the edge here, iam not getting data from the database as you can see from printed object, he just have empty properties

Comment: Read what question "*man*" ? I don't see a question-mark anywhere in your awesomely detailed "*question*" ... btw custom types are usually added in the configuration section of DoctrineBundle under `doctrine.dbal.types` in your `app/config/config.yml` or some file that gets imported into there holding the `doctrine` configuration ... see the [configuration reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html). Just my few cents "*man*" :)

Comment: Sorry i didnt mean to be rude, iam just pissed of, i did wrote whats my problem, and its not obligatory to define them there, i tryed that also, but thanks for your response ;)

Comment: While your way of adding the custom types *might* not be causing the problem ... i.e. because the real problem is most likely related to your implementation of the custom type itself ... i would recommend you still start by adding your type(s) the *symfony-way* under `doctrine.dbal.types` to make sure your current implementation does *not* cause this or any additional problems.

Comment: Well, i fixed it right now, i dont know what was exactly issue, but after i defined first EncryptionProvider in boot function, evrything worked normal

Comment: could you delete the question or add your findings/final working solution as an answer please? This way other users could benefit aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I did fix this on my own, its not general issue but ill explain here.I needed to firstly define a EncryptionProvider wich is my class that implements PHPSecLib\AES.So this is correct

```
public function boot()
{
    new EncryptionInit();
    EncryptionProvider::setCrypter(EncryptionProvider::AES, $this->container->getParameter('uapi_core.security_key'), $x = array());

    $connection = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getConnection();
    if(!Type::hasType('encrypted'))
    {
        Type::addType('encrypted', 'Uapi\CoreBundle\System\DBALType\EncryptedType');
        $connection->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('encrypted', 'encrypted');
    }


 }
```